# Error when creating c# code identifier expected

Tags: c#

I have an error of "Identifier expected" for this code. What is the problem with the code?

```
private static IEnumerable<FileInfo[]> ReturnFile(DirectoryInfo[], dirList, string fileSearchPattern) 
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirList) 
    {
        yield return dir.GetFiles(fileSearchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that there's a variable missing after DirectoryInfo[]...

Answer (score 1):

You have extra ,-mark in you method signature. Try this:

```
private static IEnumerable<FileInfo[]> ReturnFile(DirectoryInfo[] dirList, string fileSearchPattern)
```